# Why is my Kafka consumer much slower than my kafka producer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I get a stream of data which I am able to completely crawl. The data all gets put into Kafka and afterwards it gets send to Cassandra. Now the kafka consumer is very slow, much slower then the producer. I want them to be exactly the same. What can I do to achieve this result or what is wrong with my code?

Here is my Kafka consumer code in python:

```
import logging
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from kafka.consumer.kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka.consumer.multiprocess import MultiProcessConsumer
from kafka.client import KafkaClient
from kafka.producer.simple import SimpleProducer
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from dateutil.parser import parse
logging.basicConfig(filename='consumer.log', format='[%(asctime)-15s] %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
class Whitelist(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, *whitelist):
        self.whitelist = [logging.Filter(name) for name in whitelist]
    def filter(self, record):
        return any(f.filter(record) for f in self.whitelist)
for handler in logging.root.handlers:
    handler.addFilter(Whitelist('consumer'))
log = logging.getLogger('consumer')
try:
    cluster = Cluster(['localhost']); session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
    kafka = KafkaClient('localhost')
    consumer = MultiProcessConsumer(kafka, b'default',kafkatopic,num_procs=16, max_buffer_size=None)
    article_lookup_stmt = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id in ?")
    article_lookup_stmt.consistency_level = ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM
    article_insert_stmt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO articles(id, thumbnail, title, url, created_at, scheduled_for, source, category, channel,genre) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    article_by_created_at_insert_stmt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO article_by_created_at(source, created_at, article) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
    article_by_url_insert_stmt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO article_by_url(url, article) VALUES (?, ?)")
    schedules_insert_stmt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO schedules(source,type,scheduled_for,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
    axes_insert_stmt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO axes(article,at,comments,likes,reads,shares) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    while True:
        messages = consumer.get_messages(count=16)
        if len(messages) == 0:
            print 'IDLE'
            continue
        for message in messages:
            try:
                response = json.loads(message.value)
                data = json.loads(response['body'])
                print response['body']
                articles = data['articles']
                idlist = [r['id'] for r in articles]
                if len(idlist)>0:
                    article_rows = session.execute(article_lookup_stmt,[idlist])
                    rows = [r.id for r in article_rows]
                    for article in articles:
                        try:
                            if not article['id'] in rows:
                                article['created_at'] = parse(article['created_at'])
                                scheduled_for=(article['created_at'] + timedelta(minutes=60)).replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
                                session.execute(article_insert_stmt, (article['id'], article['thumbnail'], article['title'], article['url'], article['created_at'], scheduled_for, article['source'], article['category'], article['channel'],article['genre']))
                                session.execute(article_by_created_at_insert_stmt, (article['source'], article['created_at'], article['id']))
                                session.execute(article_by_url_insert_stmt, (article['url'], article['id']))
                                session.execute(schedules_insert_stmt,(article['source'],'article',scheduled_for,article['id']))
                                log.debug('%s %s' % (article['id'],article['created_at']))
                            session.execute(axes_insert_stmt,(article['id'],datetime.utcnow(),article['axes']['comments'],article['axes']['likes'],0,article['axes']['shares']))
                        except Exception as e:
                            print 'error==============:',e
                            continue
            except Exception as e:
                print 'error is:',e
                log.exception(e.message)
except Exception as e:
    log.exception(e.message)
```

EDIT:

I also added my profile results and the slow line of code seems to be

```
    article_rows = session.execute(article_lookup_stmt,[idlist])

Sun Feb 14 16:01:01 2016    consumer.out

         395793 function calls (394232 primitive calls) in 23.074 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      141   10.695    0.076   10.695    0.076 {select.select}
     7564   10.144    0.001   10.144    0.001 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
        1    0.542    0.542   23.097   23.097 consumer.py:5(<module>)
     1510    0.281    0.000    0.281    0.000 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
       38    0.195    0.005    0.195    0.005 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py:371(raw_decode)
       13    0.078    0.006    0.078    0.006 {time.sleep}
     2423    0.073    0.000    0.137    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:242(__init__)
    22112    0.063    0.000    0.095    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/util.py:73(relative_unpack)
        3    0.052    0.017    0.162    0.054 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/protocol.py:386(decode_metadata_response)
2006/2005    0.047    0.000    0.055    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/policies.py:350(make_query_plan)
     1270    0.032    0.000    0.034    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py:259(__init__)
        3    0.024    0.008    0.226    0.075 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client.py:456(load_metadata_for_topics)
       33    0.024    0.001    0.031    0.001 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/collections.py:288(namedtuple)
    15374    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 {built-in method new of type object at 0x788ee0}
      141    0.023    0.000   11.394    0.081 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client.py:153(_send_broker_aware_request)
      288    0.020    0.000    0.522    0.002 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py:84(_read_bytes)
     2423    0.018    0.000    0.029    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1216(findCaller)
      115    0.018    0.000   11.372    0.099 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/consumer/kafka.py:303(fetch_messages)
     2423    0.018    0.000    0.059    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1303(callHandlers)
    24548    0.017    0.000    0.017    0.000 {_struct.unpack}
44228/43959    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {len}
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: As it is currently stated, your question lacks details that are needed for a proper answer. Use a profiler to find out which parts of your script are slow, then try rewriting these parts to make them faster. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html for more details.

Comment: the part of my script that's slow is after for message in messages.

Comment: Your consumer issues 5 cassandra queries - there's no indication what your'e consumer does, but it seems like 5 synchronous CQL queries would potentially take quite a it longer than a trivial producer.

Comment: @JeffJirsa So you suggest to do async? MY consumer writes data to cassandra. thanks

Comment: Async is faster, sure. We can see your consumer writes to cassandra, what's your producer do?

Comment: @JeffJirsa My producer sends the urls of the articles we want to crawl.

Comment: @liori I also added my profile results as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running the consumer without saving to C*, so you can observe how much difference does it make.
If it turns out that saving to C* is a choke point (which I assume it is), you could have a thread pool (larger than 16 threads your consumer spawns) whose sole responsibility is to write to C*.

That way, you would offload the slow part of the code, which would leave only trivial parts in the consumer code.
You could use a `from multiprocessing import Pool`.
More [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

Comment: Thanks! What ifI am already doing this but it's still slow? You are  right writing to Cassandra is the choke point. But don't know why it's so slow when data increases.

Comment: If you're using the code you posted, then you're not already doing this :) But if you do this, and you notice that regardless of number of threads in your thread pool, you're still at roughly the same throughput, then you'd have to tune C*. Since we know that Cassandra's most notable feature is to always be able to accept practically unlimited amounts of data (as the horz. scale increases), that should be doable and you should post this question to C*  tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the many follow up questions, I just have one more :): If I already use multiprocess consumer why do I still need to use multithread? thanks

Comment: That way you can independently scale writing to C* from your Kafka consumer, since when reading from Kafka, you can run at most number of consumer threads as you have partitions (at least that's how Java consumer client works).